# cannot understand worldengine install

Tags: python

This is probably a little too broad of a question that may be too specific problem, but as a fiction writer with next to no familiarity with programming, I cannot seem to understand any of the provided instructions for downloading the plate tectonics world generator WorldEngine for my Windows 8, 64-dit computer. https://github.com/Mindwerks/worldengine

These are the instructions I was using. https://github.com/Mindwerks/worldengine/wiki/Installing-Worldengine-on-Windows

I have tried everything I can to get this to work, but I don't know what files I am supposed to download or not download, where to download them, or what to do with any of them. All I have managed so far is to download Python and add it to the PATH in the environment variables, and install pip. Despite this, pip is never recognized despite my following multiple sets of instructions to install it. It doesn't help any that every set of instructions I've found has failed to be specific, saying to open a cmd line without saying where to open it, or saying to add something to the PATH without specifying where to add it, or saying to download "the latest release" where there are several files available to download, none of which are clearly labeled except with jargon that I don't understand. Any other steps are irrelevant since they all involve using the pip command at some point, which doesn't do anything.

Specifically, I've done everything up to step 5, at which point "pip install wheel" just isn't recognized. In the event that I reach step 6, I don't see any zipped release files or know what to download.

What am I missing here to get this thing to work?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer since installing Python? (You technically only have to restart your cmd.exe process to reload environment variables, but a good restart never hurts)

Comment: We have now binary packages for Windows, Linux and Mac available under https://github.com/Mindwerks/worldengine/releases

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the maintainer of the project. First of all sorry, we are working on making WorldEngine easier to use on Windows.

It seems that you are stuck at installing pip (pip is a program... to download python programs and install them easily: the problem is that you need to install it first :D).

If you open the command line can you type:

```
python --version
```

What is the output?

Now you should open a browser https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and save the page (as a file with .py extension). You should save it in the same directory where you are in the command line (it is listed in the prompt). For example, if you see something like:

```
C:\foo\bar>
```

It means that you are within directory bar, inside directory foo on drive C:

at this point you should write:

```
python get-pip.py
```

What is the output of this command?

Can you now run:

```
pip --version
```

If it does not work you can try using pip as module, basically in the instructions when you read:

```
pip install ....
```

do instead

`python -m pip install ...`.

Does it help?

Feel free to ask questions on our Google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/worldengine): we will be enthusiast to help you!